# Rails listing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold, nomethoderror

I generated a scaffold and I created a casual application. I want to list the scaffold items on a sidebar, everywhere on the application (inside application.html.erb).
My left column, in *application.html.erb* looks like that:

```
>  <div id="leftcolumn">
>     <% @items.each do |link| %>
>       <%= link_to link.title, link %>
>     <% end %>
>  </div>
```

Clicking on each item would lead to it's Show method.
After running that, whenever I try to access any method of any item, it shows me the following error:

```
>     NoMethodError in Items#show
>     
>     Showing F:/Rails/items-list/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
>     where line #17 raised:
>     
>     You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
>     You might have expected an instance of Array.
>     The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

And the followed code is the left column's code.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Rails is complaining because you're trying to treat nil as an array. Without posting the line numbers for application.html.erb, I have to guess, but I'd guess that `@items` is nil.

If you're including this in your layout, then you need to make sure that your `@items` array is set on every request. Is it? One easy way of doing this would be to put a `before_filter` in your application_controller.rb.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    ...
    before_filter setup_items
    ...
    def setup_items
        @items = Item.all
    end
    ...
end
```

This assumes that all controllers using this layout extend the application controller.

Comment: It wasn't the problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Ariel, from what i understood from the question, @drewbob's answer seems bang on. Maybe you should explain the problem or question a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your controller has this:

```
@items = Item.all
```

Then in your view you want this :

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
   <% @items.each do |link| %>
     <%= link_to link.title, link if link.title%>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

It could be failing because one of the `links` does not have a title.

Comment: That's not it. All links have a title